# Updating a WPF's ObservableCollection content

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

What is the most convenient to update an ObservableCollection's data based on some fields ? I can think of many ways to do it (Linq, iterations...) but I was wondering if somebody has something proofed to offer.

```
public ObservableCollection<CCData> CCDataList =
    new ObservableCollection<CCData>();

public class CCData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public string LastTick { get; set; }

    //INotifyPropertyChanged stuff here...
}

CCDataList.Add(new CCData
        {
            Symbol = "EUR/USD",
            Time = "12:21:58"
        });

 CCDataList.Add(new CCData
        {
            Symbol = "AUD/JPY",
            Time = "12:25:40"
        });
```

**Example** 
Let's suppose I want to look in the collection for the symbol entry "EUR/USD" and update the time entry.
How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do it as you've mentioned. However I still prefer Linq hands down and would do something like this. Granted this isn't coded very defensively but you get the idea.

```
CCDataList.Where(c => c.Symbol == "EUR/USD").First().Time = DateTime.Now;
```

As you could create a simple method to update the property for you

```
public void UpdateCurrencyTime(string currencySymbol, DateTime time)
{
   var item = CCDataList.Where(c => c.Symbol == currencySymbol).FirstOrDefault();
   if(item != null)
       item.Time = time;
}
```

Comment: +1... but I thought of that but I had a few doubts on Linq regarding performance as I will do very highly frequent updates...

Comment: If your looking for pure performance it looks like pure iterative loops is the way to go take a [look at this article](http://ox.no/posts/linq-vs-loop-a-performance-test) So its a case of readability (linq) vs performance for you (iterations)

Answer (score 0):

dude the best way from performance point of view is to iterate using for loop and the first time you encounter the desired value update it and use the break to terminate the loop. foreach and enumerable class extended functions make use of extra resources like enumerator. from codeing point of view they are efficient but from performance point of view simplee looping is the best.